# How to disable fingerprint in GDM?

Tags: gdm, fingerprint-reader

I use fingerprint with success and it is integrated well, however for decryption it is not helpful during initial login. So I want to disable for GDM login. However I can not find a clear description how to do this.

It looks like there are some outdated descriptions like this, but neither of these are working:

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/login-fingerprint.html.en
http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_enable_integrated_fingerprint_reader_with_fprint

For /etc/gdm3/custom.conf I can not find a option.

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, gdm3/focal-updates,now 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.3

PS: Further there are a couple of pam modules available for gdm (fingerpint related also) but I would like to avoid to tweak there.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen enable-fingerprint-authentication false` (based on the instructions in https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/login-fingerprint.html.en) but this will affect the lock screen too.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't want to touch the pam files but because other people will find this question they might find how I did it useful.

**Use at your own risk I don't understand how exactly the gdm confings are used and why there is a separate one for fingerprint.**

This is how I did it on Debian Gnome. Should work for ubuntu.

Run

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Use spacebar and disable fingerprint if it is enabled. There should be no star there.
[image]

Go to `/etc/pam.d`. To edit stuff here u will need sudo.

```
sudo cp common-auth common-auth-nofinger
```

Now enable finger trough pam

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Backup files before editing:

```
sudo cp gdm-password gdm-password.bkp
sudo cp gdm-fingerprint gdm-fingerprint.bkp
```

The `gdm-password` and the `gdm-fingerprint` are used by the gnome login. So we want these to use the old `common-auth` config from the disabled pam (that is why we made a copy of it an renamed it).

in the `gdm-password` file replace `@include common-auth` with `@include common-auth-nofinger`

Also we will redirect `gdm-fingerprint` to `gdm-password` so that it will be actualy the same.

Either comment all the lines in `gdm-fingerprint` or delete them then add this:

```
# In order to disable the fingerprint from the gnome login I commented          
# out all the config and redirected logic to be same ass password               
@include gmd-password
```

To revert use the backuped files.
All these changes I suppose may get reset on system upgrade.